Remove row from GridDb TimeSeries
I want to remove rows from a GridDb TimeSeries but I can’t find how achieve it.
Context
Assuming the following TimeSeries Wind: [Date, speed, direction] containing the following rows:
Wind[date='Thu Aug 29 19:40:17 CEST 2024', speed=25, direction=80]
Wind[date='Thu Aug 29 19:40:18 CEST 2024', speed=-1, direction=-1]
Wind[date='Thu Aug 29 19:40:19 CEST 2024', speed=70, direction=102]
Wind[date='Thu Aug 29 19:40:20 CEST 2024', speed=51, direction=125]

How would you remove the second line with speed=-1, direction=-1 ?
What i've tried
The only way I’ve found is to :

Issue a TQL Query with all the selection clauses (WHERE speed = -1 OR direction = -1)
Iterate over all the results and for each issue a timeseries.remove(wind.date)

try (var windSeries = store.getTimeSeries("wind", Wind.class);
    var rowset = windSeries.query("select * where direction=-1").fetch()
) {
     while (rowset.hasNext()) {
        var wind = rowset.next();
        windSeries.remove(wind.date);
    }
}

What I'm looking for
Is there a more “optimal” to delete rows? I was expecting something like :
try (var windSeries = store.getTimeSeries("wind", Wind.class)) {
    windSeries.query("delete *  where direction=-1").fetch()
}

